# Anthuruim leaves have white spots

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, leaves, flowering

I'm very new to gardening and just bought an anthuruim from a nursery.

However, when I looked closely at the leaves, I found that it has some white spots.

[image: anthuruim leaves]

I'm really worried if I bought an infected plant. I tried washing the leaves with little water and my fingers, but it didn't help. With no idea and no tools at my disposal, what are my best options now?

Also some of the other leaves have brown spots and turned yellowish. The nursery guy told me it's common and they will eventually fall off like any other plant. But again, is that what is supposed to happen with anthuruims?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.